# Обработать Exception из сторонней библиотеки, где Exception не предопределён

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Есть в библиотеке **requests** метод *json()*.

Хочу обрабатывать его  исключения, "если вдруг что не так". Например сервер ответил не json-ом, а чем то другим, ну всякие там проблемы с кодировками и.т.д.

Полез в документацию, потом в исходники, и понял, что в конечном счёт в самом requests всё завязано сразу на две библиотеки:

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Соответственно сразу два вида исключений для каждой из них.

А у меня библиотека "общевойсковая", которую хотелось бы использовать в независимых условиях от установленной системы, библиотек и.т.д.

Как грамотно в таком случае прописать

```
try: 
   answer = requests.get(url, param, headers).json()
except (???, ???, ???):
   do_my_function(incorrect_answer)
```

чтобы это не зависело от библиотек, импорт который состоялся, а вместе с ними и свои определённые исключения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз уж полезли в исходники, то следует идти до конца. А ещё и документация может помочь.

В [документации](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) на requests json() сказано:

> In case the JSON decoding fails, `r.json()` raises an exception. For example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response contains invalid JSON, attempting `r.json()` raises `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

Мы должны отлавливать исключение `ValueError`:

```
try: 
   answer = requests.get(url, param, headers).json()
except ValueError:
   do_my_function(incorrect_answer)
```

Если посмотреть исходники json и simplejson, то можно увидеть, что оба пакета используют более точное исключение, унаследованное от `ValueError`: `JSONDecodeError`. Таким образом, можно сделать и так:

```
try:
    from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
except ImportError:
    from json import JSONDecodeError
...
try: 
   answer = requests.get(url, param, headers).json()
except JSONDecodeError:
   do_my_function(incorrect_answer)
```